# RegEx for searching various formats of a string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have two regular expressions:

```
([^.]*string)
((?<![.]\.)string)
```

Both work. But, I do not want to search the string that has period in it.

1) `.string`

2) `string`

For the first regex, it matches the rest of the string except period.

The second is a complete match

Regex matches against both.

I want a regex which gets only second.

Comment: Try this:

    ^string$

Comment: This is a bit vague, but from what i understand, why not use ```\w``` to not match periods. For example ```^\w+```

Comment: You are stressing on *comma* in your question but using *period* in your regular expressions.

Comment: ^string$ does not work either

Comment: You need `(?<!\.)string`

Comment: This works, (?<!\.)string

Comment: Also can you explain why this did not work ((?<![.]\.)string)

Comment: Can you explain what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: `((?<![.]\.)string)` is actually a very close solution, it is "almost" correct, but it does not work because it matches `string` that is not preceded with *two* dots. `[.]\.` matches `..` string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we wish to pass everything except for <kbd>.</kbd>, we would be passing newlines with an expression such as:

```
([\s\S]*?)(\.?)
([\w\W]*?)(\.?)
([\d\D]*?)(\.?)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OV7QWY/1).

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

If we wish to find instances of `string` without a dot such as .string or .string. or .string", then we can simply list them in [an expression similar to](https://regex101.com/r/bmPh6E/1):

```
 ([\s\S]*?)(\sstring|\x22string\x22|\x27string\x27)?
 ([\w\W]*?)(\sstring|\x22string\x22|\x27string\x27)?
 ([\d\D]*?)(\sstring|\x22string\x22|\x27string\x27)?
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Excuse me for my ignorance, but what's the difference between `([\s\S]*?)` and `(.*?)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
((?<!\.)string)
```

It uses negative look-behind.